# Sum of absolute values to convex problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Sorry if this is a very easy question but I am trying to learn convex optimization and I am facing the following question: suppose I want to find values $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in an optimization problem (a feasibility problem) such that:

$$\min_{x_1, x_2, x_3} \: 0x_1+0x_2+0x_3 \quad \text{subject to} \quad |x_1+a|+|x_2+b|+|x_3+b| \geq K $$

Could I transform that in a convex problem?

Comment: Let ${\bf x} := (x_1, x_2, x_3)$. Use the $1$-norm. Draw it for the $2$-dimensional case

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rodrigo. Using in two dimensions it does not look that the solution space is convex. Just its complement .... Then it seems that it cannot be "convexified" right?

Comment: This is not a convex constraint. You could write the absolute value exactly using binary variables and then have a mixed-integer problem.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Thanks @Michal!